# statement.executeBatch() vs statement.updateQuery() when there is only one query to be executed

Tags: java, mysql, sql, connection

OK, I know that **Batch Processing** allows to group related SQL statements into a batch and submit them with one call to the database. When you send several SQL statements to the database at once, you reduce the amount of communication overhead, thereby improving performance. In this particular situation (see code below) I don't think batching does it's sole purpose. Cause `stmt.executeBatch()` is called straight away after adding a batch(?) Wouldn't `stmt.executeUpdate()` do the same thing?

```
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    int row = e.getFirstRow();
    int col = e.getColumn();
    model = (MyTableModel) e.getSource();
    String stulpPav = model.getColumnName(col);
    Object data = model.getValueAt(row, col);
    Object studId = model.getValueAt(row, 0);
    System.out.println("tableChanded works");
    try {
        new ImportData(stulpPav, data, studId);
        bottomLabel.setText(textForLabel());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public class ImportData {    

    public ImportData(String a, Object b, Object c)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            connection = TableWithBottomLine.getConnection();
            String stulpPav = a;
            String duom = b.toString();
            String studId = c.toString();
            System.out.println(duom);
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            stmt.addBatch("update finance.fin set " + stulpPav + " = " + duom
                    + " where ID = " + studId + ";");
            stmt.executeBatch();
            connection.commit();
        } catch (BatchUpdateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
            connection.setAutoCommit(true);
            System.out.println("Data was imported to database");
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case using batch has no advantage at all. It might even introduce additional overhead over a direct `executeUpdate` (but that is driver and database dependent).

However, don't assume that batching has advantages with all JDBC drivers. I haven't looked at the specifics of MySQL, but I know there are JDBC drivers where batching internally is a normal execute for each statement in the batch.

The code in your question however has a bigger problem: it is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I should probably use prepared statement to avoid SQL injection, right?

Comment: @Paul Yes, using a prepared statement will address part of the SQL injection vulnerability. However the fact you allow the column name to be specified is a further injection risk that cannot be addressed by prepared statements.

Comment: would column names aliases solve the problem? If not, what is the right way to do it, please?

Comment: @Paul I don't see how column aliases would help you with an update statement. You might want to post a new question.